# $.get fetched data lags on mousehover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching a value from database and putting it on a hover condition.

jquery.js

```
$(".hovertext").mouseover(function(){
    $.get('test.php',function(data){
    $(".hovertext").text(data);
    });
});
$(".hovertext").mouseout(function(){
    $(".hovertext").text("See Value");
});
```

Here, `mouseover` and `mouseout` event is doing their job. But sometimes(once in 10) the **fetched data** doesn't change to **See Value** on `mouseout`

But this is working fine.

```
    $(".hovertext").mouseover(function(){
        $(".hovertext").text("Hey There");
    });
    $(".hovertext").mouseout(function(){
        $(".hovertext").text("Hellooooo")
    });
```

I hope you understand what i mean. 
Thanks in advance. 
And, Sorry for my english.

Comment: Those `$.get()` calls will not complete immediately; they involve an HTTP transaction to your server and that may involve any number of unpredictable delays.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the $.get() is an async call to your server and it might be executed after the mouseout callback, which is local and therefore faster.

Try using a flag:

```
var mouseover=false;

$(".hovertext").mouseover(function(){
    mouseover=true;
    $.get('test.php',function(data){
        if(mouseover){
            $(".hovertext").text(data);
        }
    });
});
$(".hovertext").mouseout(function(){
    $(".hovertext").text("See Value");
    mouseover=false;
});
```